# Checkout on master and execute on slave

Tags: git, jenkins, git-checkout

I want to use Jenkins to run automated hardware tests controlled by various Python scripts. I have a Jenkins master installed on a Linux server and a Jenkins slave on the Test server (a Windows Server).
I need the master to pull the test code from a GitHub repo and then the slave to execute the test code.

What is the best/simplest way for the master to pull the code and have the slave execute the code?
Can I pull the code from the slave through the master?
Only from the server I can access my GitHub repo, not from the slave.
Currently I am setting up different jobs to pull the code on the master, then copy it to the slave using plugin copyArtifacts and then execute the code on the slave. This seems cumbersome.

Comment: I believe we cannot do this, because to execute any command you your source code on that machine (be it master or slave depending on where you want to execute the command).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Jenkins Pipelines, you can use `stash` and `unstash` steps to copy over data from one node to the other, which should exactly fit your use case.

Comment: @Martin_Vegas if this helped to solve your problem, please use the checkmark on the left to mark this as solved.